# How to properly configure TilesViewResolver in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tiles

I have Spring MVC project and I would like to build views in my application using Apache Tiles. I have added some dependencies to my `pom.xml` file. I am wondering I have too many but I have had some exceptions about missing classes so I found them in some packages and have added them to classpath.

```
<!-- Tiles -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>         
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-digester3</artifactId>
      <version>3.2</version>
      <classifier>with-deps</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

This is my `ViewResolvers` configuration in Dispatcher Servlet Context. I am wondering how to properly configure them together.

```
<beans:bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
    <beans:property name="definitions">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>/WEB-INF/tiles-definitions.xml</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean> 

<beans:bean id="tilesViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView" />
    <beans:property name="order" value="0" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    <beans:property name="order" value="1" />
</beans:bean>
```

I have read this question and answer: [How to use multiple ViewResolvers in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1029193/845220) but it haven't been helpful for me. At this moment with above configurations `jsp` views works properly but for tiles addresses I am getting `HTTP Status 404`.

**EDIT**

This is my controller. The view connected with "home" is working but others - tiles aren't working.

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {        
    return "home";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/pets", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String pets(Locale locale, Model model) {
    return "pets-tiles";
}   

@RequestMapping(value = "/dogs", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String dogs(Locale locale, Model model) {
    return "dogs-tiles";
}   

@RequestMapping(value = "/cats", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String cats(Locale locale, Model model) {
    return "cats-tiles";
}
```

And this is my `tiles-definitions.xml` file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_0.dtd">
 <tiles-definitions>

  <definition name="template-main" template="/WEB-INF/views/layouts/main.jsp">
   <put-attribute name="banner-content" value="/WEB-INF/views/sections/banner.jsp" />
   <put-attribute name="title-content" value="Pet Type" />
   <put-attribute name="primary-content" value="" />
   <put-attribute name="footer-content" value="/WEB-INF/views/sections/footer.jsp" />
  </definition>

  <definition name="template-detail" template="/WEB-INF/views/layouts/detail.jsp">
   <put-attribute name="banner-content" value="/WEB-INF/views/sections/banner.jsp" />
   <put-attribute name="title-content" value="Pet Type" />
   <put-attribute name="subtitle-content" value="" />
   <put-attribute name="primary-content" value="" />
   <put-attribute name="footer-content" value="/WEB-INF/views/sections/footer.jsp" />
  </definition>

  <definition name="pet-tiles" extends="template-main">
   <put-attribute name="primary-content" value="/WEB-INF/views/contents/pets.jsp" />
  </definition>

  <definition name="dog-tiles" extends="template-detail">
   <put-attribute name="subtitle-content" value="Canines" />
   <put-attribute name="primary-content" value="/WEB-INF/views/contents/dogs.jsp" />
  </definition>

  <definition name="cat-tiles" extends="template-detail">
   <put-attribute name="subtitle-content" value="Felines" />
   <put-attribute name="primary-content" value="/WEB-INF/views/contents/cats.jsp" />
  </definition>

 </tiles-definitions>
```

They come from this tutorial: http://krams915.blogspot.com/2010/12/spring-mvc-3-tiles-2-integration.html But not working for me.

Comment: can you post your Tiles configuration file and some code from the controller class?

Comment: I have just edited my question. Could you check out it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved my problem. I don't know why it wasn't working but at this moment everything seems to be OK.

I have found and implemented `AutoTilesView` class from this url: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?78312-Spring-MVC-Noob-help-with-site-templates

Why the default `TilesView` wasn't working? `AutoTilesView` class looks like:

```
public class AutoTilesView extends TilesView {

private static final String PREFIX = "/WEB-INF/views/";
private static final String SUFFIX = ".jsp";

@Override
protected void renderMergedOutputModel(Map<String, Object> model,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception {

    ServletContext servletContext = getServletContext();
    TilesContainer container = ServletUtil.getContainer(servletContext);

    if (container == null) {
        throw new ServletException("Tiles container is not initialized. " +
                "Have you added a TilesConfigurer to your web application context?");
    }

    AttributeContext attributeContext = container.getAttributeContext(request, response);

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append(PREFIX);
    builder.append(this.getUrl());
    builder.append(SUFFIX);     

    attributeContext.putAttribute("body", Attribute.createTemplateAttribute(builder.toString()));

    super.renderMergedOutputModel(model, request, response);
}
}
```

And this is code from my Serlvet Dispatcher Context:

```
<beans:bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
    <beans:property name="definitions">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>/WEB-INF/tiles-definitions.xml</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean> 

<beans:bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="viewClass" value="cos.tam.AutoTilesView" />
</beans:bean>
```

I have removed `org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver`.

Comment: This is solution for Tiles 2.2.2 for example. I am wondering how it would be for Tiles 3.0.