# Spring Social /connect return HTTP 404

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-social, spring-social-linkedin

Spring can't find html views and im getting 404 while i'm trying to open `/connect/linkedin`. In referece to [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30249204/spring-social-connect-return-404) I double checked my paths in webapp folder. Here is my SpringSocialConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableSocial
public class SocialConfig implements SocialConfigurer {

    @Inject
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    public void addConnectionFactories(ConnectionFactoryConfigurer connectionFactoryConfigurer, Environment environment) {
        connectionFactoryConfigurer.addConnectionFactory(new LinkedInConnectionFactory("xxxxxx", "xxxxxx"));
    }

    @Override
    public UserIdSource getUserIdSource() {
        return new UserIdSource() {
            @Override
            public String getUserId() {
                Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
                if (authentication == null) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to get a ConnectionRepository: no user signed in");
                }
                return authentication.getName();
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public ConnectController connectController(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator, ConnectionRepository connectionRepository) {
        return new ConnectController(connectionFactoryLocator, connectionRepository);
    }


    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
    public LinkedIn linkedin(ConnectionRepository repository) {
        Connection<LinkedIn> connection = repository.findPrimaryConnection(LinkedIn.class);
        return connection != null ? connection.getApi() : null;
    }

    @Override
    public UsersConnectionRepository getUsersConnectionRepository(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator) {
        return new JdbcUsersConnectionRepository(dataSource, connectionFactoryLocator, Encryptors.noOpText());
    }
}
```

My HomeController with `/linkedin` mapping handler

```
@Inject
private ConnectionRepository connectionRepository;

@Inject
private LinkedIn linkedIn;

@Inject
public HomeController(LinkedIn linkedIn) {
    this.linkedIn = linkedIn;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/linkedin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(Principal currentUser, Model model) {
    Connection<LinkedIn> connection = connectionRepository.findPrimaryConnection(LinkedIn.class);
    if (connection == null) {
        return "redirect:/connect/linkedin";
    }
    model.addAttribute("profile", connection.getApi().profileOperations().getUserProfileFull());
    return "linkedin/profile";
}
```

And my WEBAPP folder with views 
[image]

As I see in logs, something happen and `/connect/*` mappings were discovered.

```
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/connect/{providerId}],methods=[POST]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController.connect(java.lang.String,org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest)
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/connect/{providerId}],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController.connectionStatus(java.lang.String,org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest,org.springframework.ui.Model)
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/connect],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController.connectionStatus(org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest,org.springframework.ui.Model)
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/connect/{providerId}],methods=[GET],params=[oauth_token]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController.oauth1Callback(java.lang.String,org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest)
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/connect/{providerId}],methods=[GET],params=[code]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController.oauth2Callback(java.lang.String,org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest)
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/connect/{providerId}],methods=[GET],params=[error]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController.oauth2ErrorCallback(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest)
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/connect/{providerId}],methods=[DELETE]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController.removeConnections(java.lang.String,org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest)
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/connect/{providerId}/{providerUserId}],methods=[DELETE]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController.removeConnection(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest)
[local
```

I'm using Thymeleaf 3.0

```
@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
    resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    resolver.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
    return resolver;
}

@Bean
public TemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    engine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
    engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
    engine.addDialect(new SpringSecurityDialect());
    return engine;
}

 private ITemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        resolver.setPrefix("/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        resolver.setCacheable(Boolean.parseBoolean(THYMELEAF_CACHE));
        return resolver;
    }
```

Dispatcher configuration

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    private final String APP_SERVLET_NAME = "x";
    private final String DISPLAY_NAME = "App";

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) {
        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(getContext()));
        CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("utf-8");
        characterEncodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);

        container.addFilter("charEncodingFilter", characterEncodingFilter).addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");
        container.addFilter("securityFilter", new DelegatingFilterProxy("springSecurityFilterChain")).addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");
        container.addFilter("apiFilter", new DelegatingFilterProxy("apiExceptionHandler"));
        container.addFilter("hidden", new HiddenHttpMethodFilter());

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherServlet = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        dispatcherServlet.register(ServletConfig.class);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet(APP_SERVLET_NAME, new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherServlet));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }

    private AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext getContext() {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(JPARepositoryConfig.class,
                ThymeleafConfig.class,
                WebSecurityConfig.class,
                SocialConfig.class,
                MailConfig.class,
                MongoRepositoryConfig.class,
                ServiceConfig.class,
                CacheConfig.class);

        rootContext.setDisplayName(DISPLAY_NAME);
        return rootContext;
    }
```

I set breakpoints in `Connection Controller` from Spring Social and non of mapped method was invoked. So I think that app configuration is mess up.

**EDIT**
I had wrong spring servlet configuration. I registered spring social controllers as root servlet.

Comment: Hey @Jakub, can you try to set `debug log level` for `spring controller`? log4j.logger.controller=DEBUG,console

Comment: could you create a simple project on GitHub to replicate this error? It will be easier to help you.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is the location of your views.

You have it under `src/main/webapp` and spring is searching for views under `src/main/resources`.

Either move all your html files to `src/main/resources/views` or change the config so that spring searches under `src/main/webapp/views`.

Check this [Example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-samples/tree/master/spring-social-showcase) the config is similar to what you have but the views are under `src/main/resources` folder.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you might need `spring.social.auto-connection-views=true` in your application.properties file

Comment: I don't have application.properties File at all. Im using Spring MVC, not Boot.

Comment: well "redirect:/connect/linkedin" in general redirects to those views if set to true, if you don't have this flag set up I guess you need to provide your own view to make connection or somehow set this flag to true (I'm not Spring MVC user so cannot help there)

Comment: pretty sure you just need to provide your own view to redirect to your social media to login since this redirects like that shouldn't work (it supposed to work only in boot with flag which provides some hidden views and configurations).

Comment: As you see I provided custom views (`webapp/views/connect/*`) maybe I should move these files somewhere else?

Comment: You redirect to "connect/linkedin" but in (webapp/views/connect/*) you dont have view "linkedin" that's why you get 404 imo.

Comment: I added `linkedin.html` and nothing changed.

Answer (score -1):

I know it's been long time, but I think I found solution for this problem.

The issue is, that your spring configuration found 'ConnectController' as bean, but it was not mapped as Controller. Also, I've checked source of ConnectController class. It turned out that it builds view names based on prefix and providerId.

Following this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19699607/4544269

I've inherited ConnectController, and overrided both 'connectView' and 'connectedView', now pointing to Freemarkers templates in WEB-INF folder.

```
@Controller
public class CustomConnectController extends ConnectController{

    @Autowired
    public CustomConnectController(
            ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator,
            ConnectionRepository connectionRepository) {
        super(connectionFactoryLocator, connectionRepository);
    }

    @Override
    protected String connectedView(String providerId){
        return "connect/facebookConnected";
    }

    @Override
    protected String connectView(String providerId) {
        return "connect/facebookConnect";
    }

   }
```